# Working detailed simple Vaadin application (not servlet) and Spring Security example

Tags: spring, spring-security, vaadin

Where can I find a fully working detailed simple Vaadin application (not servlet) and Spring Security example that logins users on simple buttonClick?

Comment: People that are downvoting reputation please argue such behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few good links might be helpful to you

[vaadin](https://vaadin.com/tutorial/-/chapter/skeleton.main-layout.html)

[vaadin](https://vaadin.com/tutorial)

[vaadin spring security](http://morevaadin.com/content/spring-security-integration/)